# problem getting specific sub strings out of a string in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get all the genes in this String, but the second while loop keeps getting me out of index error
I need all the substrings that start with ATG and end with TAA, TGA or TAG and the gene length must by dividable by 3

the code is very messy because the many tries, it is in java

```
public class HelloWorld{
 static String g = "";

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    search();
    ctgsearch();
 }
 public static void search(){
     String gen = "";
     int lenght = 0;
     int count = 0;
     int startindex = 0;
     int endindex = -2;
     int oldstart = 0;
     int oldend = 0;
     int countcg = 0;
     int longest = 0;
     int longerthansixty = 0;
     while(startindex != -1 && endindex != -1){
         if(endindex == -2)
         {
             startindex = g.indexOf("ATG", 0);
         }
         else
         {
             
             startindex = g.indexOf("ATG", endindex);
         }
         if(startindex == -1){break;}
         if (g.indexOf("TAA", startindex + 3) < g.indexOf("TGA", startindex + 3) &&
         g.indexOf("TAA", startindex + 3) < g.indexOf("TAG", startindex + 3))
         {
             endindex = g.indexOf("TAA", startindex + 1);
         }
         else
         {
             if(g.indexOf("TGA", startindex + 3) < g.indexOf("TAG", startindex + 3))
             {
                 endindex = g.indexOf("TGA", startindex + 1);
             }
             else
             {
                 endindex = g.indexOf("TAG", startindex + 1);
             }
         }
         if(endindex == -1){break;}
         gen = g.substring(startindex, endindex);
         if(gen.length() % 3 == 0){
             if(gen.length() > 57){longerthansixty++;}
             count ++;
             if(cgsearch(gen) > 0.35){countcg ++;}
             System.out.println("The gen" + count + " is: " + gen);
             System.out.println("The length is " + (gen.length() + 6));
             System.out.println("The start index is: " + startindex + ", and the end is: " + endindex);
             if (gen.length() + 6 > longest){
                 longest = gen.length() + 6;
             }
         }
         else{
         //if(endindex >= g.length()){break;}
             //endindex = startindex + 1;
             
             System.out.println("Start");
             while(gen.length() % 3 != 0)
             {
                 if (g.indexOf("TAA", endindex + 1) < g.indexOf("TGA", endindex + 1) &&
                 g.indexOf("TAA", endindex + 1) < g.indexOf("TAG", endindex + 1))
                 {
                     endindex = g.indexOf("TAA", endindex + 1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(g.indexOf("TGA", endindex + 1) < g.indexOf("TAG", endindex + 1))
                     {
                         endindex = g.indexOf("TGA", endindex + 1);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         endindex = g.indexOf("TAG", endindex + 1);
                     }
                 }
                 gen = g.substring(startindex, endindex);
             }
             count ++;
             if(cgsearch(gen) > 0.35){countcg ++;}
             System.out.println("The gen" + count + " is: " + gen);
             System.out.println("The length is " + (gen.length() + 6));
             System.out.println("The start index is: " + startindex + ", and the end is: " + endindex);
             if (gen.length() + 6 > longest){
             longest = gen.length() + 6;
             }
         }
     }
    System.out.println("Total gen is : " + count);
    System.out.println("Cg Count is : " + countcg);
    System.out.println("Longest gen is : " + longest);
 }
 public static void ctgsearch(){
     //int ctgcount = 0;
     //int ctgindex = 0;
     //while (ctgindex != -1){
         //ctgindex = g.indexOf("CTG", ctgindex + 1);
         //ctgcount++;
         //System.out.println("CTG index: " + ctgindex);
     //}
     //System.out.println("CTG is: " + ctgcount);
     String findStr = "CTG";
     int lastIndex = 0;
     int count = 0;
     while(lastIndex != -1){
         lastIndex = g.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);
         if(lastIndex != -1){
             count ++;
             lastIndex += findStr.length();
             }
     }
     System.out.println("CTG is: " + count);
 }
 public static double cgsearch(String d){
     int c = 0;
     int gg = 0;
     char cx = 'C';
     char gx = 'G';
     for(int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++){
         if(d.charAt(i) == cx){
             c++;
         }
         if(d.charAt(i) == gx){
                 gg++;
         }
     }
     //System.out.println("C Times: " + c);
     //System.out.println("G Times: " + gg);

     System.out.println("cg ratio for this gen " + (Double.valueOf(c) + Double.valueOf(gg)) / Double.valueOf(d.length()));
     return ((Double.valueOf(c) + Double.valueOf(gg)) / Double.valueOf(d.length()));
     //System.out.println("cgRatio: " + ff + ", g length: " + g.length());

     }
}
```

the string I have is :

```
ACAAGTTTGTACAAAAAAGCAGAAGGGCCGTCAAGGCCCACCATGCCTATTGGATCCAAAGAGAGGCCAACATTTTTTGAAATTTTTAAGACACGCTGCAACAAAGCAGATTTAGGACCAATAAGTCTTAATTGGTTTGAAGAACTTTCTTCAGAAGCTCCACCCTATAATTCTGAACCTGCAGAAGAATCTGAACATAAAAACAACAATTACGAACCAAACCTATTTAAAACTCCACAAAGGAAACCATCTTATAATCAGCTGGCTTCAACTCCAATAATATTCAAAGAGCAAGGGCTGACTCTGCCGCTGTACCAATCTCCTGTAAAAGAATTAGATAAATTCAAATTAGACTTAGGAAGGAATGTTCCCAATAGTAGACATAAAAGTCTTCGCACAGTGAAAACTAAAATGGATCAAGCAGATGATGTTTCCTGTCCACTTCTAAATTCTTGTCTTAGTGAAAGTCCTGTTGTTCTACAATGTACACATGTAACACCACAAAGAGATAAGTCAGTGGTATGTGGGAGTTTGTTTCATACACCAAAGTTTGTGAAGGGTCGTCAGACACCAAAACATATTTCTGAAAGTCTAGGAGCTGAGGTGGATCCTGATATGTCTTGGTCAAGTTCTTTAGCTACACCACCCACCCTTAGTTCTACTGTGCTCATAGTCAGAAATGAAGAAGCATCTGAAACTGTATTTCCTCATGATACTACTGCTAATGTGAAAAGCTATTTTTCCAATCATGATGAAAGTCTGAAGAAAAATGATAGATTTATCGCTTCTGTGACAGACAGTGAAAACACAAATCAAAGAGAAGCTGCAAGTCATGGATTTGGAAAAACATCAGGGAATTCATTTAAAGTAAATAGCTGCAAAGACCACATTGGAAAGTCAATGCCAAATGTCCTAGAAGATGAAGTATATGAAACAGTTGTAGATACCTCTGAAGAAGATAGTTTTTCATTATGTTTTTCTAAATGTAGAACAAAAAATCTACAAAAAGTAAGAACTAGCAAGACTAGGAAAAAAATTTTCCATGAAGCAAACGCTGATGAATGTGAAAAATCTAAAAACCAAGTGAAAGAAAAATACTCATTTGTATCTGAAGTGGAACCAAATGATACTGATCCATTAGATTCAAATGTAGCAAATCAGAAGCCCTTTGAGAGTGGAAGTGACAAAATCTCCAAGGAAGTTGTACCGTCTTTGGCCTGTGAATGGTCTCAACTAACCCTTTCAGGTCTAAATGGAGCCCAGATGGAGAAAATACCCCTATTGCATATTTCTTCATGTGACCAAAATATTTCAGAAAAAGACCTATTAGACACAGAGAACAAAAGAAAGAAAGATTTTCTTACTTCAGAGAATTCTTTGCCACGTATTTCTAGCCTACCAAAATCAGAGAAGCCATTAAATGAGGAAACAGTGGTAAATAAGAGAGATGAAGAGCAGCATCTTGAATCTCATACAGACTGCATTCTTGCAGTAAAGCAGGCAATATCTGGAACTTCTCCAGTGGCTTCTTCATTTCAGGGTATCAAAAAGTCTATATTCAGAATAAGAGAATCACCTAAAGAGACTTTCAATGCAAGTTTTTCAGGTCATATGACTGATCCAAACTTTAAAAAAGAAACTGAAGCCTCTGAAAGTGGACTGGAAATACATACTGTTTGCTCACAGAAGGAGGACTCCTTATGTCCAAATTTAATTGATAATGGAAGCTGGCCAGCCACCACCACACAGAATTCTGTAGCTTTGAAGAATGCAGGTTTAATATCCACTTTGAAAAAGAAAACAAATAAGTTTATTTATGCTATACATGATGAAACATCTTATAAAGGAAAAAAAATACCGAAAGACCAAAAATCAGAACTAATTAACTGTTCAGCCCAGTTTGAAGCAAATGCTTTTGAAGCACCACTTACATTTGCAAATGCTGATTCAGGTTTATTGCATTCTTCTGTGAAAAGAAGCTGTTCACAGAATGATTCTGAAGAACCAACTTTGTCCTTAACTAGCTCTTTTGGGACAATTCTGAGGAAATGTTCTAGAAATGAAACATGTTCTAATAATACAGTAATCTCTCAGGATCTTGATTATAAAGAAGCAAAATGTAATAAGGAAAAACTACAGTTATTTATTACCCCAGAAGCTGATTCTCTGTCATGCCTGCAGGAAGGACAGTGTGAAAATGATCCAAAAAGCAAAAAAGTTTCAGATATAAAAGAAGAGGTCTTGGCTGCAGCATGTCACCCAGTACAACATTCAAAAGTGGAATACAGTGATACTGACTTTCAATCCCAGAAAAGTCTTTTATATGATCATGAAAATGCCAGCACTCTTATTTTAACTCCTACTTCCAAGGATGTTCTGTCAAACCTAGTCATGATTTCTAGAGGCAAAGAATCATACAAAATGTCAGACAAGCTCAAAGGTAACAATTATGAATCTGATGTTGAATTAACCAAAAATATTCCCATGGAAAAGAATCAAGATGTATGTGCTTTAAATGAAAATTATAAAAACGTTGAGCTGTTGCCACCTGAAAAATACATGAGAGTAGCATCACCTTCAAGAAAGGTACAATTCAACCAAAACACAAATCTAAGAGTAATCCAAAAAAATCAAGAAGAAACTACTTCAATTTCAAAAATAACTGTCAATCCAGACTCTGAAGAACTTTTCTCAGACAATGAGAATAATTTTGTCTTCCAAGTAGCTAATGAAAGGAATAATCTTGCTTTAGGAAATACTAAGGAACTTCATGAAACAGACTTGACTTGTGTAAACGAACCCATTTTCAAGAACTCTACCATGGTTTTATATGGAGACACAGGTGATAAACAAGCAACCCAAGTGTCAATTAAAAAAGATTTGGTTTATGTTCTTGCAGAGGAGAACAAAAATAGTGTAAAGCAGCATATAAAAATGACTCTAGGTCAAGATTTAAAATCGGACATCTCCTTGAATATAGATAAAATACCAGAAAAAAATAATGATTACATGAACAAATGGGCAGGACTCTTAGGTCCAATTTCAAATCACAGTTTTGGAGGTAGCTTCAGAACAGCTTCAAATAAGGAAATCAAGCTCTCTGAACATAACATTAAGAAGAGCAAAATGTTCTTCAAAGATATTGAAGAACAATATCCTACTAGTTTAGCTTGTGTTGAAATTGTAAATACCTTGGCATTAGATAATCAAAAGAAACTGAGCAAGCCTCAGTCAATTAATACTGTATCTGCACATTTACAGAGTAGTGTAGTTGTTTCTGATTGTAAAAATAGTCATATAACCCCTCAGATGTTATTTTCCAAGCAGGATTTTAATTCAAACCATAATTTAACACCTAGCCAAAAGGCAGAAATTACAGAACTTTCTACTATATTAGAAGAATCAGGAAGTCAGTTTGAATTTACTCAGTTTAGAAAACCAAGCTACATATTGCAGAAGAGTACATTTGAAGTGCCTGAAAACCAGATGACTATCTTAAAGACCACTTCTGAGGAATGCAGAGATGCTGATCTTCATGTCATAATGAATGCCCCATCGATTGGTCAGGTAGACAGCAGCAAGCAATTTGAAGGTACAGTTGAAATTAAACGGAAGTTTGCTGGCCTGTTGAAAAATGACTGTAACAAAAGTGCTTCTGGTTATTTAACAGATGAAAATGAAGTGGGGTTTAGGGGCTTTTATTCTGCTCATGGCACAAAACTGAATGTTTCTACTGAAGCTCTGCAAAAAGCTGTGAAACTGTTTAGTGATATTGAGAATATTAGTGAGGAAACTTCTGCAGAGGTACATCCAATAAGTTTATCTTCAAGTAAATGTCATGATTCTGTTGTTTCAATGTTTAAGATAGAAAATCATAATGATAAAACTGTAAGTGAAAAAAATAATAAATGCCAACTGATATTACAAAATAATATTGAAATGACTACTGGCACTTTTGTTGAAGAAATTACTGAAAATTACAAGAGAAATACTGAAAATGAAGATAACAAATATACTGCTGCCAGTAGAAATTCTCATAACTTAGAATTTGATGGCAGTGATTCAAGTAAAAATGATACTGTTTGTATTCATAAAGATGAAACGGACTTGCTATTTACTGATCAGCACAACATATGTCTTAAATTATCTGGCCAGTTTATGAAGGAGGGAAACACTCAGATTAAAGAAGATTTGTCAGATTTAACTTTTTTGGAAGTTGCGAAAGCTCAAGAAGCATGTCATGGTAATACTTCAAATAAAGAACAGTTAACTGCTACTAAAACGGAGCAAAATATAAAAGATTTTGAGACTTCTGATACATTTTTTCAGACTGCAAGTGGGAAAAATATTAGTGTCGCCAAAGAGTCATTTAATAAAATTGTAAATTTCTTTGATCAGAAACCAGAAGAATTGCATAACTTTTCCTTAAATTCTGAATTACATTCTGACATAAGAAAGAACAAAATGGACATTCTAAGTTATGAGGAAACAGACATAGTTAAACACAAAATACTGAAAGAAAGTGTCCCAGTTGGTACTGGAAATCAACTAGTGACCTTCCAGGGACAACCCGAACGTGATGAAAAGATCAAAGAACCTACTCTATTGGGTTTTCATACAGCTAGCGGGAAAAAAGTTAAAATTGCAAAGGAATCTTTGGACAAAGTGAAAAACCTTTTTGATGAAAAAGAGCAAGGTACTAGTGAAATCACCAGTTTTAGCCATCAATGGGCAAAGACCCTAAAGTACAGAGAGGCCTGTAAAGACCTTGAATTAGCATGTGAGACCATTGAGATCACAGCTGCCCCAAAGTGTAAAGAAATGCAGAATTCTCTCAATAATGATAAAAACCTTGTTTCTATTGAGACTGTGGTGCCACCTAAGCTCTTAAGTGATAATTTATGTAGACAAACTGAAAATCTCAAAACATCAAAAAGTATCTTTTTGAAAGTTAAAGTACATGAAAATGTAGAAAAAGAAACAGCAAAAAGTCCTGCAACTTGTTACACAAATCAGTCCCCTTATTCAGTCATTGAAAATTCAGCCTTAGCTTTTTACACAAGTTGTAGTAGAAAAACTTCTGTGAGTCAGACTTCATTACTTGAAGCAAAAAAATGGCTTAGAGAAGGAATATTTGATGGTCAACCAGAAAGAATAAATACTGCAGATTATGTAGGAAATTATTTGTATGAAAATAATTCAAACAGTACTATAGCTGAAAATGACAAAAATCATCTCTCCGAAAAACAAGATACTTATTTAAGTAACAGTAGCATGTCTAACAGCTATTCCTACCATTCTGATGAGGTATATAATGATTCAGGATATCTCTCAAAAAATAAACTTGATTCTGGTATTGAGCCAGTATTGAAGAATGTTGAAGATCAAAAAAACACTAGTTTTTCCAAAGTAATATCCAATGTAAAAGATGCAAATGCATACCCACAAACTGTAAATGAAGATATTTGCGTTGAGGAACTTGTGACTAGCTCTTCACCCTGCAAAAATAAAAATGCAGCCATTAAATTGTCCATATCTAATAGTAATAATTTTGAGGTAGGGCCACCTGCATTTAGGATAGCCAGTGGTAAAATCGTTTGTGTTTCACATGAAACAATTAAAAAAGTGAAAGACATATTTACAGACAGTTTCAGTAAAGTAATTAAGGAAAACAACGAGAATAAATCAAAAATTTGCCAAACGAAAATTATGGCAGGTTGTTACGAGGCATTGGATGATTCAGAGGATATTCTTCATAACTCTCTAGATAATGATGAATGTAGCACGCATTCACATAAGGTTTTTGCTGACATTCAGAGTGAAGAAATTTTACAACATAACCAAAATATGTCTGGATTGGAGAAAGTTTCTAAAATATCACCTTGTGATGTTAGTTTGGAAACTTCAGATATATGTAAATGTAGTATAGGGAAGCTTCATAAGTCAGTCTCATCTGCAAATACTTGTGGGATTTTTAGCACAGCAAGTGGAAAATCTGTCCAGGTATCAGATGCTTCATTACAAAACGCAAGACAAGTGTTTTCTGAAATAGAAGATAGTACCAAGCAAGTCTTTTCCAAAGTATTGTTTAAAAGTAACGAACATTCAGACCAGCTCACAAGAGAAGAAAATACTGCTATACGTACTCCAGAACATTTAATATCCCAAAAAGGCTTTTCATATAATGTGGTAAATTCATCTGCTTTCTCTGGATTTAGTACAGCAAGTGGAAAGCAAGTTTCCATTTTAGAAAGTTCCTTACACAAAGTTAAGGGAGTGTTAGAGGAATTTGATTTAATCAGAACTGAGCATAGTCTTCACTATTCACCTACGTCTAGACAAAATGTATCAAAAATACTTCCTCGTGTTGATAAGAGAAACCCAGAGCACTGTGTAAACTCAGAAATGGAAAAAACCTGCAGTAAAGAATTTAAATTATCAAATAACTTAAATGTTGAAGGTGGTTCTTCAGAAAATAATCACTCTATTAAAGTTTCTCCATATCTCTCTCAATTTCAACAAGACAAACAACAGTTGGTATTAGGAACCAAAGTGTCACTTGTTGAGAACATTCATGTTTTGGGAAAAGAACAGGCTTCACCTAAAAACGTAAAAATGGAAATTGGTAAAACTGAAACTTTTTCTGATGTTCCTGTGAAAACAAATATAGAAGTTTGTTCTACTTACTCCAAAGATTCAGAAAACTACTTTGAAACAGAAGCAGTAGAAATTGCTAAAGCTTTTATGGAAGATGATGAACTGACAGATTCTAAACTGCCAAGTCATGCCACACATTCTCTTTTTACATGTCCCGAAAATGAGGAAATGGTTTTGTCAAATTCAAGAATTGGAAAAAGAAGAGGAGAGCCCCTTATCTTAGTGGGAGAACCCTCAATCAAAAGAAACTTATTAAATGAATTTGACAGGATAATAGAAAATCAAGAAAAATCCTTAAAGGCTTCAAAAAGCACTCCAGATGGCACAATAAAAGATCGAAGATTGTTTATGCATCATGTTTCTTTAGAGCCGATTACCTGTGTACCCTTTCGCACAACTAAGGAACGTCAAGAGATACAGAATCCAAATTTTACCGCACCTGGTCAAGAATTTCTGTCTAAATCTCATTTGTATGAACATCTGACTTTGGAAAAATCTTCAAGCAATTTAGCAGTTTCAGGACATCCATTTTATCAAGTTTCTGCTACAAGAAATGAAAAAATGAGACACTTGATTACTACAGGCAGACCAACCAAAGTCTTTGTTCCACCTTTTAAAACTAAATCACATTTTCACAGAGTTGAACAGTGTGTTAGGAATATTAACTTGGAGGAAAACAGACAAAAGCAAAACATTGATGGACATGGCTCTGATGATAGTAAAAATAAGATTAATGACAATGAGATTCATCAGTTTAACAAAAACAACTCCAATCAAGCAGCAGCTGTAACTTTCACAAAGTGTGAAGAAGAACCTTTAGATTTAATTACAAGTCTTCAGAATGCCAGAGATATACAGGATATGCGAATTAAGAAGAAACAAAGGCAACGCGTCTTTCCACAGCCAGGCAGTCTGTATCTTGCAAAAACATCCACTCTGCCTCGAATCTCTCTGAAAGCAGCAGTAGGAGGCCAAGTTCCCTCTGCGTGTTCTCATAAACAGCTGTATACGTATGGCGTTTCTAAACATTGCATAAAAATTAACAGCAAAAATGCAGAGTCTTTTCAGTTTCACACTGAAGATTATTTTGGTAAGGAAAGTTTATGGACTGGAAAAGGAATACAGTTGGCTGATGGTGGATGGCTCATACCCTCCAATGATGGAAAGGCTGGAAAAGAAGAATTTTATAGGGCTCTGTGTGACACTCCAGGTGTGGATCCAAAGCTTATTTCTAGAATTTGGGTTTATAATCACTATAGATGGATCATATGGAAACTGGCAGCTATGGAATGTGCCTTTCCTAAGGAATTTGCTAATAGATGCCTAAGCCCAGAAAGGGTGCTTCTTCAACTAAAATACAGATATGATACGGAAATTGATAGAAGCAGAAGATCGGCTATAAAAAAGATAATGGAAAGGGATGACACAGCTGCAAAAACACTTGTTCTCTGTGTTTCTGACATAATTTCATTGAGCGCAAATATATCTGAAACTTCTAGCAATAAAACTAGTAGTGCAGATACCCAAAAAGTGGCCATTATTGAACTTACAGATGGGTGGTATGCTGTTAAGGCCCAGTTAGATCCTCCCCTCTTAGCTGTCTTAAAGAATGGCAGACTGACAGTTGGTCAGAAGATTATTCTTCATGGAGCAGAACTGGTGGGCTCTCCTGATGCCTGTACACCTCTTGAAGCCCCAGAATCTCTTATGTTAAAGATTTCTGCTAACAGTACTCGGCCTGCTCGCTGGTATACCAAACTTGGATTCTTTCCTGACCCTAGACCTTTTCCTCTGCCCTTATCATCGCTTTTCAGTGATGGAGGAAATGTTGGTTGTGTTGATGTAATTATTCAAAGAGCATACCCTATACAGTGGATGGAGAAGACATCATCTGGATTATACATATTTCGCAATGAAAGAGAGGAAGAAAAGGAAGCAGCAAAATATGTGGAGGCCCAACAAAAGAGACTAGAAGCCTTATTCACTAAAATTCAGGAGGAATTTGAAGAACATGAAGAAAACACAACAAAACCATATTTACCATCACGTGCACTAACAAGACAGCAAGTTCGTGCTTTGCAAGATGGTGCAGAGCTTTATGAAGCAGTGAAGAATGCAGCAGACCCAGCTTACCTTGAGGGTTATTTCAGTGAAGAGCAGTTAAGAGCCTTGAATAATCACAGGCAAATGTTGAATGATAAGAAACAAGCTCAGATCCAGTTGGAAATTAGGAAGGCCATGGAATCTGCTGAACAAAAGGAACAAGGTTTATCAAGGGATGTCACAACCGTGTGGAAGTTGCGTATTGTAAGCTATTCAAAAAAAGAAAAAGATTCAGTTATACTGAGTATTTGGCGTCCATCATCAGATTTATATTCTCTGTTAACAGAAGGAAAGAGATACAGAATTTATCATCTTGCAACTTCAAAATCTAAAAGTAAATCTGAAAGAGCTAACATACAGTTAGCAGCGACAAAAAAAACTCAGTATCAACAACTACCGGTTTCAGATGAAATTTTATTTCAGATTTACCAGCCACGGGAGCCCCTTCACTTCAGCAAATTTTTAGATCCAGACTTTCAGCCATCTTGTTCTGAGGTGGACCTAATAGGATTTGTCGTTTCTGTTGTGAAAAAAACAGGACTTGCCCCTTTCGTCTATTTGTCAGACGAATGTTACAATTTACTGGCAATAAAGTTTTGGATAGACCTTAATGAGGACATTATTAAGCCTCATATGTTAATTGCTGCAAGCAACCTCCAGTGGCGACCAGAATCCAAATCAGGCCTTCTTACTTTATTTGCTGGAGATTTTTCTGTGTTTTCTGCTAGTCCAAAAGAGGGCCACTTTCAAGAGACATTCAACAAAATGAAAAATACTGTTGAGAATATTGACATACTTTGCAATGAAGCAGAAAACAAGCTTATGCATATACTGCATGCAAATGATCCCAAGTGGTCCACCCCAACTAAAGACTGTACTTCAGGGCCGTACACTGCTCAAATCATTCCTGGTACAGGAAACAAGCTTCTGATGTCTTCTCCTAATTGTGAGATATATTATCAAAGTCCTTTATCACTTTGTATGGCCAAAAGGAAGTCTGTTTCCACACCTGTCTCAGCCCAGATGACTTCAAAGTCTTGTAAAGGGGAGAAAGAGATTGATGACCAAAAGAACTGCAAAAAGAGAAGAGCCTTGGATTTCTTGAGTAGACTGCCTTTACCTCCACCTGTTAGTCCCATTTGTACATTTGTTTCTCCGGCTGCACAGAAGGCATTTCAGCCACCAAGGAGTTGTGGCACCAAATACGAAACACCCATAAAGAAAAAAGAACTGAATTCTCCTCAGATGACTCCATTTAAAAAATTCAATGAAATTTCTCTTTTGGAAAGTAATTCAATAGCTGACGAAGAACTTGCATTGATAAATACCCAAGCTCTTTTGTCTGGTTCAACAGGAGAAAAACAATTTATATCTGTCAGTGAATCCACTAGGACTGCTCCCACCAGTTCAGAAGATTATCTCAGACTGAAACGACGTTGTACTACATCTCTGATCAAAGAACAGGAGAGTTCCCAGGCCAGTACGGAAGAATGTGAGAAAAATAAGCAGGACACAATTACAACTAAAAAATATATCTAGGGCCTCATGGGCCCAGCTTTCTTGTACAAAGTGGT
```

Comment: Just use regular expression i will try to write

Comment: You can check the expression : https://regex101.com/r/Lo3qhc/1

Comment: In the given string shown in the example, the regex `ATG(?:.{3})*?(?:TAA|TGA|TAG)` will find the one and only sequence, which is from index 42 to 10299, i.e. almost the entire string. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kyzkSg/1) for demo.

Comment: Interesting there are a lot of cases like ATGGCTTAG

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Perhaps a missing requirement is that `ATG` should be at an offset that is divisible by 3?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
final String text ="Your string";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ATG)(\\w*?)(TAA|TGA|TAG)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
     String group2 = matcher.group(2);
     if (group2.length() % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + group2 + matcher.group(3));
     }
}
```

Comment: that was magical, Thanks Gurkan,
do you have any idea how to make the regular expression checks if the group(2) length is multiple of 3, because I need any strings that starts with ATG, some times there is TAA, TGA or TAG after but they make a wrong string, so I should keep looking for the next end that makes the gene length dividable by 3

Comment: I tried to add X{3} after the ? in group(2), but didn't work

Comment: Incorrect result. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495605/problem-getting-specific-sub-strings-out-of-a-string-in-java#comment110523781_62495605).

Comment: I guess you are dealing with something similar to genetic algorithm.